# Entire number continuum is equivalent to any finite segment: Courant and Robbins Book

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading *What is Mathematics?* by Richard Courant and Herbert Robbins.

They discuss about the fact the $\Bbb{R}$ is not countable and after they say

> «it is easy to show that the entire number continuum is equivalent to any finite segment, say the segment from 0 to 1 with the endpoints excluded. The desired biunique correspondence may be obtained by bending the segment at $1/3$ and $2/3$ and projecting from a point »

Here is the figure is the book:

[image]

Unfortunately I don't understand the construction. Not sure what "projecting from a point" mean here and how can I get the bijection.

Can someone explain how to construct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine that the dot at the center is a light bulb. Then every point on the cup-shaped part of the figure has a shadow point on the line. (That's what "projection" means in this context.)

The points on the cup shaped figure correspond to the points on the unit interval using the "bending" Courant and Robbins describe.

Comment: Interesting, I get the idea. It seems (for me at least) difficult to "write formally" such a function ?!

Comment: @Byung well.. if you define the dimensions of the "cup" and the distance between the base of the cup and the number line, its just a matter of similar triangles.  Although not the exact same construction, a very similar tool is the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) in complex analysis.  You could even look at the $x$-$z$ plane where $y=0$ to get a feel for the real numbers only case.  Instead of the cup shape being like $\sqcup$ it is a circle, and instead of it residing over the real line it is centered on it, but the concept is otherwise the same.

Comment: @Byung I agree that writing the formal function would be difficult, and the result would be ugly. But Courant and Robbins are trying to make the _idea_ clear, and (for you) they have now succeeded.

Comment: @EthanBolker and thanks to you!

Comment: @Byung . To map the interval $(-1,1)$  to $\mathbb R$ you can also  use the function $f(x) =\tan (\pi x /2)$.